# read text file as dictionary using python and make some replacement using this dictionary

Tags: python

I read text file like

```
awsm  awesome 
gr8   great
```

as dictionary i need to replace acronym words with it's correct one in dictionary i used this code but it give me error " replace() argument 2 must be str, not list" code :

```
def acronym(text):
    with open('acronym.txt') as fin:
        rows= (line.split('\t') for line in fin )
        d = { row[0]:row[1:] for row in rows }
    acronym_words = []
    words = word_tokenize(text)
    for word in words:
        for candidate_replacement in d:
            if candidate_replacement in word:
                word = word.replace(candidate_replacement, d[candidate_replacement])
        acronym_words.append(word)
    acronym_sentence = " ".join(acronym_words)
    return acronym_sentence

acronym(" we are awsm and gr8") # to test function
```

Comment: the row[1:] is likely spitting out a list of strings as it's saying go to the end of the list. When you really need it to be just a singular value/string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In:

```
d = { row[0]:row[1:] for row in rows }
```

`row[1:]` is a slice which produces a list. Just use `row[1]` since the dictionary values should be a string representing a single word, not a list.

Comment: it doesn't give me the desired output i need this code acronym(" we are awsm and gr8") give me result of "we are awesome and great" this is the shape of dictionary with more extra words {'a$$': ['a**\n'], 'a&f': ['always and forever\n'], "a'ight": ['alright\n'], 'a.i.m.': ['aol instant messanger\n'], 'a/l': ['age and location\n']}